# Err while deploying to devnet on Solana

Tags: anchor, solana-program, deploy, anchor-spl, mpl-token-metadata

The build is successful using `anchor build`. and when i deploy my program using `anchor deploy` i am getting below error

[image]

anchor_cli = 0.28.0

Comment: Have you try cargo build-sbf to build the program?

Comment: Yes i tried but same problem .

Comment: This is a problem in the built program. You may need to start fresh by deleting `target/deploy` and re-running `anchor build`